# Category of $K$-operator algebras equivalent to $K\text{-}\mathrm{vec}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

Is the category of operator algebras over a field $K$ (that is, $K$-algebras that are the endomorphism algebra of some vector space) equivalent to the category of vector spaces over the same field $K$?

And if so, is there some general theorem about when this is true for the arbitrary category? Since the operator algebra is just the endomorphisms for each vector space.

Comment: What is your definition of the "category of operator algebras"?

Comment: algebra of linear transformations of vector space to itself @EricWofsey

Comment: That doesn't the question at all.  What is an object of your "category of operator algebras"?  What is a morphism?

Comment: morphisms between two "operator algebras over a field K" are maps between algebras that preserve addition and multiplication and scalar multiplication @EricWofsey

Comment: So, an object of this category is a $K$-algebra which is of the form $End(V)$ for some $K$-vector space $V$, and a morphism is a (unital?) $K$-algebra homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusion. morphism does not have to be unital.

Answer (score 3):

No, these categories are very far from being equivalent.  There is a correspondence between their objects but the morphisms are totally different.  For instance, the category of operator algebras has an object $K$ (the endomorphisms of a 1-dimensional vector space) which has exactly two endomorphisms (the identity and the zero map).  The category of vector spaces has no such object unless $K=\mathbb{F}_2$.  (In the case $K=\mathbb{F}_2$, you can say there are exactly four morphisms from the vector space $K$ to the vector space $K^2$, whereas there is no operator algebra with exactly four morphisms from $K$, where in both categories $K$ is characterized as an object with exactly two endomorphisms.)

Comment: Hmm good point, the reason I ask is because in the [wiki article for equivalent categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) it claims that the category of finite real vector spaces is equivalent to the category of finite real square matrices @EricWofsey

Comment: That category is totally different from your category of operator algebras.  In that category, matrices are the _morphisms_.